# Help with a summation problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I can't find a way to prove this one.

I would appreciate help on this one:

Without any special identity,

How to prove this is correct?

$$\sum_{i=n}^{5n}\frac{1}{i} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{4n}\frac{1}{1+i/n}$$

this part is the first step of proving that the

$$LIM(\sum_{i=n}^{5n}\frac{1}{i}) = ln(5)$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the lower summation index changes as well. So you just substitute $i+n$ for $i$ and subtract $n$ from the lower and upper summation index. Then you get a sum of $\frac{1}{i+n} = \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+i/n}$.

Comment: so easy. cant believe i missed that.
thank you.